# Button Change State directly from mysql db in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to change the state of a button directly from mysql db.
States are:
    1. Enable 
    2. Disable.
I have an `Asynctask` that executes some query and give some result like true or false
If it gives true then enable button else disable.

I want the button to change the state automatically if some one change value in db manually
What will be the best or any approach to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a thread that cyclically listens for changes is the best solution. Nevertheless, using AsyncTask is not the preferred way to accomplish this, since an AsyncTask, by design, should be used only for short running operations.
Use a worker thread, pass an handler to the UI Thread to your worker thread, and update the button through this handler.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

    private final long WAITING_TIME = 5000;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean current_state = false;

    MyThread(Handler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    run(){
        new_state = // retrieve from database;
        if(new_state != current_state){
            handler.send(new Message().setData(new Bundle().putBoolean("STATE",new_state)));
            current_state = new_state;
        }
        this.wait(WAITING_TIME);
    }
}
```

And in your Activity you parse the arrived message and do the necessary changes (you don't really need to parse the message if this is the only thread communicating with the handler, since you know that each new message means a change in the button state). So, for example in your onCreate() callback:

```
handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(Message message){
        if(message.getBundle().getBoolean("STATE"))
            //activate button
        else
            //deactivate button
    }
}

new MyThread(handler).start();
```

Another solution would be to use a reactive agent in your application that waits for notifications from the database. But this is not a good design since it will turn both your application and your backend into a degenerate server.